# How to implement Gradient Descent with special error function and penalty

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbCX6.png)

This special loss function makes me confused. Whether I need to set the if else condition before each computes and how to implement this penalty into my function?

```
def bgd_l2(data, y, w, eta, delta, lam, num_iter):

return new_w, history_fw
```

This is what my function should look like, the data is a two-dimensional numpy array with each row being a feature vector, y is a one-dimensional numpy array of target values, w is a one-dimensional numpy array corresponding to the weight vector, eta is the learning rate, delta and lam are parameters of the objective function.

Could you give me some advice on how to construct the core algorithm of this function?

Comment: Have you taken the gradient of such function with respect to w?

Comment: I am new to machine learning, I only have learned the theory. This is the first time I write my own gradient function.

Comment: You should post this in: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/